# can i use promises as middleware to handle error like this?

Tags: express, promise, async-await

for eg if i create a middleware like this

```
module.exports = {
    asyncErrorHandler: (fn) => 
        (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req,res,next))
                .catch(next);
        }
    }
```

and use it in my routes eg:

```
router.get('/:id', asyncErrorHandler(postShow));
```

where postShow is in controller here

```
async postShow(req, res, next){
    let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('posts/show', {post})
    },
```

but i didnt understand how this promise is handling error in my route. I mean promise is something which helps in handling callbacks but how is it handling errors here?

Answer (score 0):

That code works in companion with an error middleware at the end of your routing:

```js
    // Middleware at the end of our app
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { // Every error called in catch(next) will be received here
      res.render('error', { errorMessage: err.message}); // A general error template
    });
```

If you dont use the `asyncErrorHandler`, you would have to call next in every single catched error, that makes your code really verbose and repetitive:

```js
    // THIS IS NOT HOW TO MANAGE ERROR CORRECTLY

    router.get('/:id', async postShow(req, res, next){
      try {
        let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        res.render('posts/show', {post})
      } catch (error) {
        next(error) // Call next manually, since we are not using the handler
      }
    }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i there any alternative of this asyncErrorHandler? I mean is this a good practise to create a middleware like this which consist of a promise to catch error?
Someone tole me i can use express-async-errors which is an npm package.

Comment: I have never used `express-async-errors` but seems like it applies the same async handler automatically to all routes. So its up to you to apply it verbosely (in this case everyone will know whats happening with the errors in routes) or silently (cleaner but could be a bit confusing maybe since it acts as a side-effect).